# buscar y reemplazar en una lista según nombre de archivo

Tags: python, condiciones, variables

tengo un problema, o mas que un problema un desconocimiento, estoy haciendo un programa en el que le das una string como esta:

```
archivos = "_V6A3489,_V6A3495,_V6A3502,_V6A3512,_V6A3518,_V6A3542,_V6A3549,_V6A3551,"
archivos2 = archivos.replace(",", ".CR2'," )
archivos3 = archivos2.replace("_", "'_")
print(archivos3)
```

El problema que tengo es que no siempre los archivos empezaran por "_", si no que empezaran por otro caracter como "-", he pensado en poner un condicional if para si contiene "_V6A", haga el replace de arriba y si empieza por otra cosa, otra condición, pero no se como indicarle al if que busque dentro de esa cadena, si alguien me lo puede indicar le estaría agradecido, un saludo y gracias.

EDICIÓN: voy a poner un ejemplo general de lo que quiero hacer. Yo quiero que el usuario introduzca un input que va a ser una de estas 2 formas:

> _V6A3489,_V6A3495,_V6A3502,_V6A3512,_V6A3518,_V6A3542,_V6A3549,_V6A3551

o de esta forma:

> 6T9A3489,6T9A3495,6T9A3502,6T9A3512,6T9A3518,6T9A3542,6T9A3549,6T9A3551

por lo que el programa en verdad tendría este codigo:

```
archivos = input("Escribe tus archivos: ")
archivos2 = archivos.replace(",", '.CR2, ')
archivos3 = archivos2.replace("_", "'_")
print(archivos3)
```

EL PROBLEMA DE ESTO es que en caso de que sea la primera opción, sería correcto, pero para la segunda no. Entiendo que usando el if es posible hacerlo, pero no se como indicarle al if que si el input contiende "_V6A" ejecute este codigo o si contiene "6T9A" ejecute otro codigo, ahora si gracias y saludos.

Comment: Sin saber el formato general de la cadena (ejemplo [nombre1][_ o -][nombre2]...) no hay mucho que decir. Pero si todos los nombres de archivo se separan con comas, no convendría primero separar la cadena en partes usando las comas de separación?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tengo 100% claro cuál es el resultado que esperas, pero imagino que lo que quieres es que para cada item en la entrada, quieres concatenar comita al inicio, y luego la cadena .CR2' al final. Si este es el caso, puedes utilizar "list comprehensions":

```py
archivos = input("Escribe tus archivos: ")
archivos2 = [a for a in archivos.split(',') if a != '']
print(archivos2)
```

Los resultados para los dos casos que incluiste serían:

```
["'_V6A3489.CR2'", "'_V6A3495.CR2'", "'_V6A3502.CR2'", "'_V6A3512.CR2'", "'_V6A3518.CR2'", "'_V6A3542.CR2'", "'_V6A3549.CR2'", "'_V6A3551.CR2'"]
["'6T9A3489.CR2'", "'6T9A3495.CR2'", "'6T9A3502.CR2'", "'6T9A3512.CR2'", "'6T9A3518.CR2'", "'6T9A3542.CR2'", "'6T9A3549.CR2'", "'6T9A35.CR2'"]
```

Comment: @ffargfan gracias, eso es exactamente lo que quiero, me has sido de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: @PedroAngelFernandezLax qué bueno!! No olvides de votar/marcar la respuesta como correcta ;)